# Where can I find pre-trained fully convolutional neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I know that fully convolutional neural networks can be used for classifying images of arbitrary sizes.
I would like to use some pre-trained fully-convolution neural networks for extracting features in a dataset with images of different sizes. Where can I find such a network?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

- image models from huggingface that can be used as image encoders, like [clip-ViT from sentence-transformers](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/clip-ViT-B-32) in Pytorch/Tensorflow
- in Tensorflow/PyTorch you can manipulate CNN models by dropping some layers. In PyTorch models that are based on torch.nn.Sequential are easy to manipulate, like in [this code](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/mlutil/blob/master/mlutil/feature_extraction/images.py#L84).